# Which Stack Exchange site is for asking about images?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have a bunch of jpg images that won't open on multiple PC's and appear to be corrupt. I would like to provide an example image and hexdump to see if someone could help figure out the problem. Which Stack Exchange site is best suited for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd go for [Super User](https://superuser.com/)  for that.

Failing that, someone on [Photography](https://photo.stackexchange.com) might be able to help.

But Super User first.